# Getting the pixel value of BMP file

Tags: c, pixel, bmp

i got a question for reading an bmp image. How can i get the pixel value(R, G, B values) in an bmp image?
Can anyone help me using the C programming language?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easy way would be to find a good image manipulation library for your chosen platform and use that.

- **Linux** [ImLib](http://freshmeat.net/projects/imlib/) / [GDK-Pixbuf (Gnome/GTK)](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gdk-pixbuf/) / [QT Image (KDE/Qt)](http://doc.trolltech.com/qq/qq17-imageio.html) should be able to do what you need.
- **Windows** I'm not familiar with the appropriate system library, but an [MSDN Search for "Bitmap"](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=bitmap&ac=8) is probably a good place to start.
- **Mac OSX** Cocoa has some image manipulation capabilities, see [this article](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Images/Images.html).

The hard way would be to open the file and actually interpret the binary data within. To do that you'll need the [BMP File Specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format). I'd recommend trying the easy way first.

Answer (score 15):

Note: you may need to grab an extra byte for the alpha values if your BMP has alpha channel. In that case image would be `image[pixelcount][4]`, and you would add another `getc(streamIn)` line to hold that fourth index. My BMP turned out to not need that.

```
 // super-simplified BMP read algorithm to pull out RGB data
 // read image for coloring scheme
 int image[1024][3]; // first number here is 1024 pixels in my image, 3 is for RGB values
 FILE *streamIn;
 streamIn = fopen("./mybitmap.bmp", "r");
 if (streamIn == (FILE *)0){
   printf("File opening error ocurred. Exiting program.\n");
   exit(0);
 }

 int byte;
 int count = 0;
 for(i=0;i<54;i++) byte = getc(streamIn);  // strip out BMP header

 for(i=0;i<1024;i++){    // foreach pixel
    image[i][2] = getc(streamIn);  // use BMP 24bit with no alpha channel
    image[i][1] = getc(streamIn);  // BMP uses BGR but we want RGB, grab byte-by-byte
    image[i][0] = getc(streamIn);  // reverse-order array indexing fixes RGB issue...
    printf("pixel %d : [%d,%d,%d]\n",i+1,image[i][0],image[i][1],image[i][2]);
 }

 fclose(streamIn);
```

~Locutus

Comment: Isn't there a header chunk you need to get past before you hit the image data?

Comment: @Anon What if my file is jpeg?

Answer (score 7):

You need to study the BMP file format. It is easier to read uncompressed 24-bit BMP files. They just contain a header at the beginning and RGB values of each pixel.

To start with this, check the example of 2x2 bitmap image at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format. Follow the below steps.

1. Create the 2x2 BMP image shown on Wikipedia.
2. Open the file in binary mode using your C program.
3. Seek to byte position 54.
4. Read 3 bytes.

The bytes would be 0, 0 and 255 respectively. (Not sure whether the order is RGB. I had done this long back and I think the order is not RGB. Just verify this.)

As simple as that! Study the header of the BMP to understand more about the format.