# .bmp processing in C

Tags: c, image-processing

I need to do a program in C or C++ (preference in C), that reads a black and white .bmp and makes a histogram with the levels of gray(0 to 255) in each pixel.
I tried looking for libraries that might help me, but so far i havent found anything and didnt even start. 
Can anyone guide me through this? I have practicly no knowledge in C, and this has to be done in this language.
I have seen OpenCV and this ImageClass.h library but nothing helped.
How should i start, and does anyone have any material that actually might help me study to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: These kind of questions are explicitly _off-topic_ here. Read point #4 from this [help center article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Hint: `int freq[256];`

Comment: Some people suggesting C++ and libraries, but this can be done very easily in C without extra waffle. Lookup the spec of the BMP file format. Then your program should open the file, read the header data into a struct and all following data into and array. Then iterate on the array to create your histogram. Start at following link maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968561/getting-the-pixel-value-of-bmp-file?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the individual pixel data from the bmp file in C++, it's much easier to use a library - i.e. [stb_image](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h) is a very simple to use header-only-library for loading various image files. But there are many other libraries out there, which can do the same (i.e. [CImg](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cimg/), [CBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t1yfd35(v=vs.140).aspx) if you're on windows, [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/), ...). [OpenCV](https://www.google.co.jp/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiUnvvXlsHSAhVFE7wKHQJaB-kQFggtMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fopencv.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNGUr-UTYvy3hRjaFyy2oCg43JU9Vw) can load images, but it can do much more complex tasks too - i.e. apply various common algorithm to image data. For just calculating a simple histogram OpenCV is maybe overkill.

Once you can access the raw pixel data from the bmp file in a array-like structure, calculating the histogram is straight forward: Just loop over every pixel and increase a counter depending on the color-value. In case of a grayscale image, this can be 0 (for black), 255 (for white) or any value in between. A histogram is simply the frequency of pixels in all possible colors.

```
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int width, height, bpp;
  unsigned char* pixels = stbi_load("grayscale.bmp", &width, &height, &bpp, 1);
  int histogram[256] = { 0 };
  for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      histogram[pixels[x + y * height]]++;
    }
  }
  stbi_image_free(pixels);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you realy helped me a lot with that, i was almost using OpenCV. Ill try the ones you recommended. Thanks again.

Comment: @RodrigoDias You're welcome! If the answer helped you, please mark it as accepted answer by clicking on the checkmark on the left side of the answer. Thank you!